# Sonarqube duplicated blocks of code between POJOs

Tags: java, sonarqube

There are two POJOs **Market** and **MarketDTO** in two packages.

**Market** is a mapping object for JSON response from remote service.

**MarketDTO** is a response object which will be exposed via our service.

There are some data massage from **Market**->**MarketDTO**. They have some common fields and both have unique fields as well. 
There are 3 common fields such as **id**, **name** and **status**.

However, Sonarqube indicates their getters and setters as **duplicated blocks of codes to be removed**. Is this actually bad code or I should just mark it as **false positive**?

Comment: If it's marking standard property accesssors, I'd go as far as to file it as a bug against SonarQube.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say your choices are to extract a common ancestor class from Market and MarketDTO, or mark the duplicated blocks issues Won't Fix. (They're *not* really false positives, are they?)

Comment: Thanks, both options sound acceptable for me. Just one more question, how SonarQube defines this rule on accessors? If two Java beans are totally irrelevant but only accidentally have 3 fields with same names (e.g. common ones like id, name etc.), are they still considered as duplication?

Comment: It simply looks at the number of duplicate tokens in a row, and takes no notice whatsoever of semantics (how could it?)

Comment: I guess so too. Then it is very likely say two classes **Person** and **Market** which both only have three fields **id**, **name**, **status**, are their accessors duplicated in the eyes of SonarQube? If they are not, then why **Market** and **MarketDTO** are? As @chrylis said, accessors may better be left out in duplication code scanning.

Comment: If you want to discuss the philosophy of duplication detection, then you should open a thread on the Google group (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/sonarqube)

Answer (score 5):

You can exclude this in Sonar by going to 
Administration > General Settings > Analysis Scope > Duplication Exclusions
and excluding folders containing your entities - e.g. **/entity/**

Comment: Is there any properties that can be used in pom.xml, like we have `<sonar.coverage.exclusions>` for excluding entity from coverage